# bValidator radio button not working

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Can anyone understand why this will not validate. I'm using jquery 1.11.1 and latest version of bValidator.

```
 <p id="surgery-yes"><label for="yes">Yes</label> 
<input name="surgery" data-bvalidator="required"   value="Yes" type="radio" />
</p>

<p id="surgery-no"><label for="no">No</label> 
<input name="surgery" value="No" type="radio" /></p>
</p>
```

I have the required set on the first radio button (yes) and no matter whether I select 'yes' or 'no' I am allowed to submit the form without an error. If I don't select either, then I get the "this is a required field" on the first radio. But then regardless of whether I select 'yes' or 'no' - the form will submit.

I've read the documentation a lot and can't figure this out for the life of me! Any help would be great :)

Thanks,
Garry.

Answer (score 0):

create your own validating function and do the check.

**jQuery**

```
$('form selector').data('bValidator').getValidators().checkradio = function(elem){
    if(elem.value == "Yes")
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="surgery-yes"><label for="yes">Yes</label> 
    <input name="surgery" data-bvalidator="checkradio,required" value="Yes" type="radio" />
</p>

<p id="surgery-no"><label for="no">No</label> 
    <input name="surgery" data-bvalidator="checkradio,required" value="No" type="radio" /></p>
</p>
```

**UPDATE**

**jQuery**

```
$('form selector').data('bValidator').getValidators().checkradio = function(elem){
    if($('[name="surgery"]:checked').val() == "Yes")
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="surgery-yes"><label for="yes">Yes</label> 
    <input name="surgery" data-bvalidator="checkradio,required" value="Yes" type="radio" />
</p>

<p id="surgery-no"><label for="no">No</label> 
    <input name="surgery" value="No" type="radio" /></p>
</p>
```

NOTE: use the updated jquery and html